# Adding elements of a class together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of notifications that all share the same class. I need to create a notification 'total', preferably using javascript/jQuery. I've been trying to get the elements of the classes, and then to add them together to create my total. However, I am currently struggling.

My current code looks like this:

```js
$(function notificationTotal() {
  var notifcationCount = document.getElementsByClassName("notificationBadge");
  alert(notificationCount);
  $('#notificationTotal').html(notifcationCount);
});
```

```css
.notificationBadge {
  display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px);
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  color: white;
  font: bold 15px/13px Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 4px 3px 0 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notificationTotal" class="notificationBadge"></div>
<div id="secondNotification" class="notificationBadge">3</div>
<div id="thirdNotification" class="notificationBadge">2</div>
```

I'm aware that I'm getting notificationTotal is not defined. However, I have declared it at least... This could be a case where I'm quite tired but any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let me see if I got this right, you want to sum the contents of your notification divs?

Comment: `notifcationCount` is an html collection.... Total sounds like you wanted to add up all the numbers so you need to loop.

Comment: @João Pedro R. Carvalho correct, without having to type their individual IDs

Comment: `notifcationCount` is missing an `i` - try copy+paste your variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue you have is that you have a typo. You've used `notificationCount` and `notifcationCount` (note the missing `i` here). This needs to be corrected.

With regards to your goal of getting the total of the values in the `.notificationBadge` elements, you need to loop through them all and add their text content before setting the `text()` of `#notificationTotal` to show the output. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var total = 0;
  $('.notificationBadge').each(function() {    
    total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
  });
  $('#notificationTotal').text(total);
});
```

```css
.notificationBadge {
  display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px);
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  color: white;
  font: bold 15px/13px Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 4px 3px 0 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notificationTotal" class="notificationBadge"></div>
<div id="secondNotification" class="notificationBadge">3</div>
<div id="thirdNotification" class="notificationBadge">2</div>
```

Comment: Well this is certainly one step closer for me. I'll most likely be accepting this as the answer. When implemented into my code it's coming back with 0 or NaN regardless of the value of the notification badges... Any hints as to what this could be? I understand if the information is too vague to provide an answer :)

Comment: In that case I would assume the HTML is different to what's shown in the question

Comment: Unfortunately not as it's a direct copy and paste (hence the spelling errors shown in the original) ... Not to matter, I'm sure I can figure out what's wrong from here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments pointed out, you've just have a typo in your code. The variable that you've declared is not the same that you're using inside the `alert`.

Comment: This is only half the issue.

Comment: I've just noticed, I misunderstood the question. Anyhow I see your answer if way more complete than mine, I've voted it.